# How to have radio buttons in horizontal way in orbeon forms?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

As I want to make a survey form like this.

[image]

Comment: Since you used the tag `orbeon`, I imagine that you'd like to create this with Orbeon Forms; is this correct? If it is, are you writing XForms by hand or using Form Builder?

Comment: @avernet using form builder

Comment: For those reading through the comments here, I've posted an answer below, based on the fact that this question is asked in the context of Form Builder. -Alex

Comment: @avernet Can we send Arabic data instead of English and store in local database in above UI form ?

Comment: Akshay, certainly. All text, whether part of the form definition, or captured by users is stored in Unicode at all levels, so you can use Arabic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see how having the questions laid out on lines and the answers in columns makes sense in this case, but you can't create this exact layout right now just with Form Builder. For now, if using Form Builder, the values of the checkboxes will need to be repeated for each questions, as follows:

[image: Questions, each with their answers]

Comment: What can be the other way to achieve the above layout?

Comment: @avernet  What can be the other way to achieve the above layout in horizontal way?

Comment: @AkshayNimbalkar This layout isn't supported by Form Builder. You could achieve this if you were writing XForms "by hand", but it doesn't seem to be your case. So I'm afraid there currently is no workaround for Form Builder.

Comment: @avernet I need to know, Why this Horizotal layout is not supported by Form Builder ? I mean this is most common layout for Survey Form.

Comment: @AkshayNimbalkar Hi Akshay, there is no particularly deep reason for that. The "reason" is that there are only 24 hours in a day, and 7 days in a week ;). But I hope we'll get to this one sooner rather than latter. In the meantime, you can always use the class, as mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

just use table for it

```
<table class="my-table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Lorem.</th>
    <th>Porro.</th>
    <th>Voluptatibus.</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some 2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css for align radio(input) at center of table cell

```
.my-table td{
  text-align: center;
}
.my-table input[type=radio]{
  display: inline;
}
```